# Cloning div with unique ID doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty sure I'm close but I don't know what I'm missing:

```
var newId = 1;
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $("#new-div").attr('id', 'new-div' +newId++).clone().appendTo("#myDiv");
});
```

I set breakpoints: I can see the counter auto-incrementing, but the cloned div does not appear where it should. I get no errors.  HTML for this:

```
 <div id="secret-div" style="display: none;">
        <div>This is new div number </div>
      </div>
      <p><a id="trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">Please, add an element</a></p>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: just added it, sorry for the omission.

Comment: Where is your `#new-div` in your html?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sMRt3/

Comment: @max7 I've updated my answer to work for your specific use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're changing the ID of your element before cloning and appending, resulting in 2 elements with the same ID, breaking your selector and code.

[Fixed Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gdvb/10/)

HTML:

```
<div id="secret-div" style="display:none;">
    <div>This is new div number <span class="spnNewDivNumber"></span></div>
</div>
<p><a id="trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">Please, add an element</a></p>
<div id="myDiv"></div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var newId = 1;
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    var $newSecretDiv = $("#secret-div").clone().attr('id', 'new-div' + newId++);
    $newSecretDiv.show().appendTo("#myDiv");
    $newSecretDiv.find('.spnNewDivNumber').text(newId - 1);
});​
```

Comment: excellent expansion of my original code.  In truth, the core problem was noted by 3dgoo: I removed #new-div and never replaced it!  My chaining order was also incorrect but the first error was primary.  Nevertheless, what you wrote was great.  Question: can you explain the use of var $newSecretDiv, specifically the use of the $ for setting the variable and why a it would not work without (I'm assuming) invoking the jQuery object.

Comment: The reason for appending $ before the variable names is to clearly mark that variable as a jQuery object. Without the $, in a large solution, I or a team member may forget that this is already a jQuery object and write unnecessary code that will degrade performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is applying the new id before the clone, which means it's changing the id of the existing div. This in turn means that the next time the click handler is called, there won't be a div matching the selector '#new-div'.

Try applying the id after either the clone, or after inserting it into the DOM:

```
var newId = 1;
$("#trigger").click(function(){
    $("#new-div").clone().attr('id', 'new-div' +newId++).appendTo("#myDiv");
});
```

OR

```
var newId = 1;
$("#trigger").click(function(){
    $("#new-div").clone().appendTo("#myDiv").attr('id', 'new-div' +newId++);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to clone the #new-div unless your current div is named 'new-div'. Also you are changing the id of the original div rather than creating a new one with the generated id.